# Get files within a folder, within another folder?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I am trying to create a mini tool for myself that checks the directory of "**C:\Logs**"

Within **C:\Logs** I have many folders with random names. I want to be able to check within all the folders inside **C:\Logs** and within those folders, check if the created date is old or not so that I can remove them programmatically.

Here is what I have so far...

```
Try
    Dim CreatedDate As DateTime
    Dim Todays_Date As DateTime = Today.Date
    Dim DirInfo As DirectoryInfo
    Dim Time_Span As TimeSpan
    Dim DirList As New List(Of String)

    For Each SubDir As String In Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Logs")
        DirInfo = New DirectoryInfo(SubDir)
        CreatedDate = DirInfo.CreationTimeUtc

        Time_Span = Todays_Date - CreatedDate

        If Time_Span .Days > 10 Then
          DirList .Add(SubDir)
          DirInfo.Delete(True)
        Else
          'No Dir found or Dir is not  > 10
        End If
    Next
End Try
```

This currently gets all the folders from within C:\Logs and delete any **folders** older than 10 days.  However, I only want to delete **FILES** within C:\Logs\ ****

Since I have a list of folders from C:\ via :

`For Each SubDir As String In Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Logs")`

Would I have to do something like this to get all the files within those folders?

```
        For Each SubFile As String In Directory.GetFiles(SubDir)
            'Check date of each file and delete if older than 10 days?
        Next
```

Comment: In the actual state, you will only read the subfolders that are **in the root** of `C:\Logs`. If you want to browse the whole tree of directories you have to code a recursive function, ie : a function that calls itself. Example : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306666/how-to-recursively-search-directories-by-using-visual-basic-2005-or-vi

Comment: I really hate recursive functions haha! My professor was right though, sometimes they're useful

Comment: a recursive functions can be dangerous, but ARE NECESSARY in some situations like this one.

Comment: Is is really?  I'm under impression that thiere are a lot of folder is folder `C:/Logs` and the structure is not deeper than two folders. Is it?

Comment: You're right, the structure isn't as big, but it's not too bad to get some practice with recursive functions. It actually only goes C:\Logs\XX and that's it. However, in the near future the C:\Logs folder is going to have a deeper structure.

Comment: What about `For Each SubDir As String In Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Logs","*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track your suggested inner loop is correct one thing more that you need is `FileInfo` class that can get metadata about files and you do it the same as you did for folder.

Comment: Since its been a few hours now and no one else has commented, I'll mark this as the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub TestIO()
    Dim fld As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Logs")
    fld.EnumerateFiles().
        Where(Function(f) (Date.Now - f.CreationTimeUtc) > TimeSpan.FromDays(10)).
        ToList().
        ForEach(Sub(f) f.Delete())
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

To get rid of `ToList` call to work with handy `ForEach` method, you could add extension method which would work with IEnumerable directly (this would be welcome in .NET Framework). This extension method would look like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (enumerable == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Argument {nameof(enumerable)} is null.");
        }

        using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                action(enumerator.Current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```